# jQuery image preload order

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preload

I'm having troubles adapting a jQuery image preload script in just one aspect: I can't figure out how to ensure, that my images are loaded/displayed in the order of my image array.

At the moment every time I reload the page the images are displayed in a different order. (Everything except the image order works fine alreday.)

Can anyone help me fixing this?

The relevant code:

```
    (function($) {
        var imgList = [];
        $.extend({
            preload: function(imgArr, option) {
                var setting = $.extend({
                    init: function(loaded, total) {},
                    loaded: function(img, loaded, total, bild) {},
                    loaded_all: function(loaded, total) {}
                }, option);
                var total = imgArr.length;
                var loaded = 0;

                setting.init(0, total);
                for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                    imgList[i] = ($("<img />")
                        .attr("src", imgArr[i])
                        .load(function() {
                            loaded++;
                            setting.loaded(this, loaded, total, this.src);
                            if(loaded == total) {
                                setting.loaded_all(loaded, total);
                            }
                        })
                    );
                }
           }
        });
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $.preload([
                "image1.jpg",
                "image2.jpg",
                "image3.jpg"
            ], {
                init: function(loaded, total) {
                    var z = 0;
                    while (z < total) {
                        z++;
                        $("section nav").append('<img id="e'+z+'" src="all/blank.png" alt=""/>');
                    }
                },
                loaded: function(img, loaded, total, bild) {
                    $("#e"+loaded).prop("src",bild);
                },
                loaded_all: function(loaded, total) {
                    //all done!
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Update:

In the end i solved it with a completely different, much shorter script I wrote from scratch. It starts adding as much (very small) dummy images as placeholders to my image container as the array contains real images and loads each image only after the previous one is finished:

```
imgs = new Array("number1.png","number2.png","number3.png");

for (i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
  $("section nav").append('<img id="e'+i+'" src="blank.png" alt=""/>');
}

fin(0);

function fin (n) {
  $('#e'+n).attr('onload', 'fin('+n+')');
  $("#e"+n).attr("src", imgs[n]).load( function() {
    fin ((n+1));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you append the loaded img to the position of the number of images that are currently loaded, i.e. the images are placed in the order they are loaded.

You actually want them to be ordered on `var i` :

```
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    imgList[i] = ($("<img />")
        .attr("src", imgArr[i])
        .load(function() {
            loaded++;
            setting.loaded(this, i, total, this.src);  // i instead of loaded
            if(loaded == total) {
                setting.loaded_all(loaded, total);
            }
        })
    );
}
```

But this won't work since `i` will be the same as `total` at the time the image is loaded, so all images will go to position `total`. Not what you want!

So we need to wrap it in a self calling anonymous function to get access to the correct `i` value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {

    // wrap in function to get access to the right i

    (function(img) {
        imgList[img] = ($("<img />")
            .attr("src", imgArr[img])
            .load(function() {
                loaded++;
                setting.loaded(this, img, total, this.src);  // img instead of i
                if(loaded == total) {
                    setting.loaded_all(loaded, total);
                }
            })
        );
    })(i);
}
```

Replace your for loop with this one and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you delay the download of each image until the previous is done (which would be a bad idea), you can't guarantee in what order they will be downloaded.

The browser will typically download several images in parallell, to optimize throughput. Combine this with the unpredictable download speed and differing file sizes, and the files will be done in pretty much any order.

If it is the visual effect you want, you have to solve that separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your `loaded` callback will never be called in order, since images load asynchronously. However, you should change `loaded_all` to pass the original array instead. That way your handler can deal with the images in order.

```
if(loaded == total) {
    setting.loaded_all(imgArray);
}
```